# Turning a simple password generator into a GUI

Tags: python, user-interface

I am in the infant stages of programming. I wrote a script to generate 4 random words to use as a password. I was able to get it to run fine in python shell. But I want to convert it into a standalone GUI application. Your advice is appreciated. The Script is:

```
from random_words import RandomWords
rw = RandomWords()
input_variable1=input("What is the first letter of your first password?")
input_variable2=input("What is the first letter of your second password?")
input_variable3=input("What is the first letter of your third password?")
input_variable4=input("What is the first letter of your fourth password?")
word1 = rw.random_word(input_variable1)
word2 = rw.random_word(input_variable2)
word3 = rw.random_word(input_variable3)
word4 = rw.random_word(input_variable4)
print word1
print word2
print word3
print word4
```

Comment: It's like "I've got a fidget spinner spinning, how do I make a helicopter?"

Comment: There are too many different ways to do this, and they are way too complicated to get into here. Look for a good python GUI tutorial, and prepare to spend a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write a GUI to display the text "Hello World!" on the screen.  When that is tested and working, add a way to select a single letter.  Read that letter and display instead a word from your word list starting with that letter.  Test is and get it working.

Repeat three more times for four words, and display them as a single passphrase.

If you have a problem, show us what you have written and we will help you get it working.